# MKMapView or CLLocationManger - to determine user's current location

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mkmapview, mapkit, cllocationmanager

There are two classes that help regarding map plotting and determining user location - `MKMapView` and `CLLocationManager`.

`MKMapView` has a delegate “`didUpdateUserLocation`” that tells the user’s current location. At the same time, `CLLocationManger` has a delegate “`didUpdateToLocation`” and it also does the same thing.

My question is when to use `MKMapView` and `CLLocationManager`. I am able to get current location of the device from `MKMapView` then why and when should I use `CLLocationManager`? I tried to get it but I am still not sure.

Comment: It is almost the same thing. The MapView might use core location internally to find user's location. If you dont need any uI but still need locatiin go with core locatiion otherwise use mapview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to use CLLocationManager which is used internally by the MKMapView, so if you don't need to use the map, just use the below code from the location manager.

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
locationManager.delegate = self;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Just don't forget to store the locationManager instance somewhere in your class and you can implement the delegate like this.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Error detecting location %@", error);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    CLLocation* location = (CLLocation*)locations.lastObject;
    NSLog(@"Longitude: %f, Latitude: %f", location.coordinate.longitude, location.coordinate.latitude);
}
```

EDIT

You can get the address of the user based on their location using Apple's Geo coder

```
// Use Apple's Geocoder to figure the name of the place
    CLGeocoder* geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler: ^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Error in geo coder: %@", error);
        }
        else {
            if (placemarks.count == 0) {
                NSLog(@"The address couldn't be found");
            }
            else {
                // Get nearby address
                CLPlacemark* placemark = placemarks[0];

                // Get the string address and store it
                NSString* locatedAt = [[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
                location.name = locatedAt;

                NSLog(@"The address is: %@", locatedAt);
            }
        }
    }];
```

Comment: I need to determine the device location even if location service is turned off onto the device. What is the correct way to determine user's current location in this scenario?

Comment: If the location service is turned off (or the user has denied location permission to your app) then you cannot determine the user's location

Comment: You can't because the user didn't give you the permission to detect his location

Comment: Ok..so is there anyway to determine user's state and country?

Comment: This is another case, you can use Apple Geo coding to determine the user's address based on their location (longitude and latitude), but again you can't get the location without the user permission

Comment: I edited my answer to add the geo coder code for you

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confusing the `MKMapView` property [showsUserLocation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKMapView/showsUserLocation) with `CLLocationManager`.

As a convenience MKMapView's allow you to simply enable a property to show the users current location on the map UI. This is really handy if you only need to show the user where they are on a map.

However, there are demonstrably many other use cases where simply showing location on a map is not enough and this is where `CLLocationManager` comes in.

Consider for example a running/training application, where a record of user locations is required to calculate running distance, or even an example from one of my own applications, where by I needed to find the users location (lat/long) to calculate distance to various train stations in real time to identify which was closest for the user. In these examples there is no need for a MapView so using a LocationManager is the right choice.

Anytime you need to programmatically interact with the users location and don't require a map UI basically!